# Opening PDFs Denied Access Google Drive in Nautilus (Files)

Tags: nautilus, pdf, google-drive

I've logged in to my Google account in the Ubuntu 22.04 settings. A link to my Google drive appears in Nautilus. I'm able to open photos and doc files, but when I try to open PDFs I receive an error message, "Unable to open document "[file:// etc.] ... Error opening file ... Permission denied.

How can I fix this problem? I've looked online and mostly am finding information regarding the Google desktop version of google drive.

Comment: This is happening for me as well

Comment: I know, that doesn't help much, but I'm experiencing the same problems with Google Drive on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. Opening PDF files with the default PDF viewer fails, even from the default file manager Files. But PDF is not the only content type, it also fails for e.g html files: if you try to open them, instead of in the default browser they are opened in the Text Editor.
Any advice?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I tried to install another pdf application and made it default to open the pdf files. But that application is also unable to open the pdf. Perhaps, this means that the bug is with Nautilus and not pdf application. I tried to file the bug but found it quite tedious. Will prefer to wait and let this bug be resolved.

Comment: From Stephane V: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/867749
Modify the Apparmor security profile with these two commands :

        sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils , 
        sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/evince

Comment: @HaywardOblad thanks for that, you should turn that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem with the Document Viewer(Evince) not Nautilus

**Disable One Profile**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

If this doesn't work, you can install atril document viewer and set that as your default, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't want to mess around with the persmission on AppArmor so I installed Atril and set it as default PDF viewer. Thanks!

Comment: The above tip didn't help me for evince, also I have the same problem with other PDV viewers and editors I tried (e.g. `qpdfview`). But thanks for the tip with `atril`, that one works!

Answer (score 2):

**I would not recommend messing with the AppArmor** settings as it's a safety-critical feature of Linux kernel and it's a workaround rather than providing a lasting solution.

I solved this by **re-installing the Document Viewer** (Evince) but instead of using the Ubuntu `.deb` distribution, installing as a [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) (from Flathub). The sandbox distribution design of Flatpak seems not to suffer from this issue with AppArmor permissions.

1. You need to uninstall the current package installation.

```
sudo apt-get remove evince
```

2. If you already haven't done so, you need to install & activate [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/).

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

3. Activate the [Flathub](https://flathub.org/home) repository.

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

4. Finally, install Document Viewer again (as a Flatpak distribution package).

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Evince
```

Comment: If one wants to install a different packaging format only to fix this evince issue, using the built-in 'sudo snap install evince' will also fix it. No permission issue from evince on gio mounted volume.

Comment: @OmidKhalili the snap version is way behind the other packaging formats, one disadvantage

Comment: I agree some packages are outdated, but at least I have a unified experience and can only type the package name on the terminal to open what I want. Typing evince on the terminal when the deb version is installed or the snap version is installed has the same result. Instead with flatpak I have to flatpak run org.gnome.Evince  (This is nonsense to me and reading https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/994 says I'm not alone.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was also hesitant to mess around with AppArmor settings.