# Ubuntu 22.04 Nautilus unable to open pdf files from Google Drive

Tags: pdf

I have Ubuntu22.04 installed. I have enabled Google Online account. Using Nautilus, I am able to open all types of files (Libre office etc.) directly by clicking them on the Google drive folder. However, I can not open pdf files using Document Viewer by double clicking them.
The default application for .pdf files is document viewer. Instead, if I install okular (KDE PDF application) & make it default, it is able to open files (obviously, I don't want to do it.
The screen shot of what happens on trying to open the file in Document viewer is as attached.

Comment: I think this may be relevant to your issue. https://askubuntu.com/a/1436784/1223818

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening PDFs Denied Access Google Drive in Nautilus (Files)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404075/opening-pdfs-denied-access-google-drive-in-nautilus-files)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I **cannot see your screenshot** of the actual issue. If you're getting any errors such as "Unable to open document "[file:// etc.] ... Error opening file ... Permission denied, then it may be related to permissions.

I solved this by re-installing the Document Viewer (Evince) but instead of using the Ubuntu `.deb` distribution, installing as a [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) (from Flathub). The sandbox distribution design of Flatpak seems not to suffer from this issue with AppArmor permissions.

1. You need to uninstall the current package installation.

```
sudo apt-get remove evince
```

2. If you already haven't done so, you need to install & activate [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/).

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

3. Activate the [Flathub](https://flathub.org/home) repository.

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

4. Finally, install Document Viewer again (as a Flatpak distribution package).

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Evince
```