# On 22.04, Nautilus sftp remote connection 'evince' gives 'unable to open document ... operation not supported'

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, sftp, evince

I am running 22.04 and when I connect to a remote server via sftp I started getting the error below. EDIT: I just realized that this only occurs for PDF files, and PNG files open in a preview as expected.

[image: 22.04-evince-sftp-operation-not-supported]

This started happening after updating from 20.04 and I am not sure how to diagnose the problem further, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a different error than the question posted here [Opening PDFs Denied Access Google Drive in Nautilus (Files)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404075/opening-pdfs-denied-access-google-drive-in-nautilus-files)

but the solution there ended up working for me.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **an issue with the Document Viewer** (Evince), not Nautilus.

**May be solved by** re-installing the Document Viewer (Evince) but instead of using the Ubuntu `.deb` distribution, installing it as a Flatpak (from Flathub). The sandbox distribution design of Flatpak seems not to suffer from issues with AppArmor permissions.

1. You need to uninstall the current package installation.

```
sudo apt-get remove evince
```

2. If you already haven't done so, you need to install & activate [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/).

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

3. Activate the [Flathub](https://flathub.org/home) repository.

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

4. Finally, install Document Viewer again (as a Flatpak distribution package).

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Evince
```